Attaching a printer on subsidiary mesh net
I have a printer (Brother HL-2349D) that used to work fine as a wifi network printer for the macOS, Windows and Ubuntu computers in my household.  Then I did two things:  I updated to Ubuntu 24.04, and I installed a Deco mesh network that is I think subsidiary to the original network (one of the nodes is attached by ethernet cable to the Fios router).  The Linux computer is on the mesh network.  I now cannot install the printer on the Linux computer.  I don' know whether the problem is the installation of 24.04 or the fact that the printer is still on the original Fios network with the other computers while the Linux computer is on the mesh.
I have the IP address of the printer, but installing a network printer seems to require some other sort of address:  there are several versions in the printer dialog in Settings but none of them works with the IP address.  I tried a search using nmap, and it yields the same IP address as the printer reports.  Ping works to that address.
I tried to install using the dialog that starts with "printers" in the activities screen, which for some reason is different from the one in Settings.  That one appeared to let me install using the IP address, and got the correct name for the printer.  However, it also warned "this printer may not exist" and failed to print a test page.  Perhaps the name of the printer was left over from the previous installation under 22.04--I'm not sure what gets carried over.  But if it is getting the name from the printer, that must mean there is communication and something else is wrong.
Where do I go from here?
